# Strings and memory usage

Tags: macros, robust-commands

The TeX engine was originally written in Pascal before dynamic memory allocation was generally available. Modern implementations tend to be done in C. To qualify as TeX an implementation has to pass a standard test, which probably does not pay attention to string types and memory usage.

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\buffer{x}%
\let\test=\buffer
\edef\buffer{\buffer,x}%
\verb$\buffer$ = \buffer

\verb$\test$ = \test
\end{document}
```

The question is, does the `\let` make a copy of `\buffer` or does it simply point to where `\buffer` is currently stored in memory?  If the former, TeX would need to practice dynamic memory allocation on a string level. If the latter, every string ever allocated remains in memory until the program is done. This would explain why putting too many `tikzpicture`s uses up all the resources.

Comment: not sure what your test file is  trying to demonstrate, but memory for token list is reclaimed once no more csnames point to the list, tex.web says:     Examples such as
$$\.{\\def\\m\{\\def\\m\{a\}\ b\}}$$
explain why reference counts would be needed even if \TeX\ had no \.{\\let}
operation: When the token list for \.{\\m} is being read, the redefinition of
\.{\\m} changes the |eqtb| entry before the token list has been fully
consumed, so we dare not simply destroy a token list when its
control sequence is being redefined.

Comment: Well, I would assume, that `\let` does indeed make copy of the code. Otherwise `\let\A\B` and redefining `\B` later on would have the same code for `\A` and `\B` (like pointers). Or is this too easy?

Comment: A tikzpicture wouldn't normally stress token memory so much but can use a lot of box/node memory that can't be reclaimed until the page is shipped out, so if you have a lot of tikz on the page (or in pending floats) you are holding a lot of nodes in memory.

Comment: You should read the chapter in `tex.web` related to the hash table (from page 102 of `tex.pdf` that you can read with `texdoc tex` on TeX Live).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer too easy:-)

Comment: @egreg - I got a copy of tex.web from CTAN.  From what I read, TeX doesn't use Pascal or C strings, but rather creates linked lists of character-nodes.  It definitely implements dynamic memory allocation (easy for linked lists) and it is reasonable (albeit difficult) to determine when a linked list is no longer accessed by any csnames.

Comment: Roughly speaking: TeX implements its own local dynamic allocation in statically allocated (from OS point of view) array called "main memory". The token lists (macro bodies), generated boxes etc. are saved here. The eqtb table is a list of pointers to meanings of csnames (meanings are stored in main memory if they are macros). TeX disposes the memory by free_avail() function (section 121 of tex.web) if the last pointer in eqtb table to this part of main memory is removed or if saved boxes are not needed any more. `\let\a=\b` creates only new item in eqtb table, doesn't copy the meaning.

Comment: @wipet Looks like an answer to me :-)

Comment: @wipet - More to the point, I will accept it as an answer and remove this question from the "unanswered" list.

Comment: @wipet: please convert (copy) your comment into an answer as it answers the question to the questioner's satisfaction.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question was answered in the comments